# Hangfire Multiple servers

Tags: c#, .net-core, hangfire

I am building a .net core web application, in the server side I am adding hangfire for scheduled tasks and for long run tasks. in the Startup.cs file I added:

```
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

and in the configure function I added this:

```
app.UseHangfireServer();
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
```

Now the problem is whenever I run the application, a new instance of the server shows up in the dashboard. 
[image]

is there a way to make sure that only one server is running? or if I can turn off the server when I stop the application (IIS) and start it again when I run the application

Comment: The old instance should be removed after a little while.

Comment: true... thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

This seems to address some of the issues.  It should clear up any servers that haven't been active in the last 15 seconds.  I currently have this is my application startup.cs. Doesn't feel like the correct solution, but limited by what they offer.

```
        // Clean up Servers List
        Hangfire.Storage.IMonitoringApi monitoringApi = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
        JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().RemoveTimedOutServers(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));

        app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions
        {
            WorkerCount = 1,
            Queues = new[] { "jobqueue" },
            ServerName = "HangfireJobServer",
        });

        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("ProcessJob", () => YourMethod(), AppSettings.JobCron, TimeZoneInfo.Local, "jobqueue");
```

Comment: Running multiple server instances like you suggest here are obsolete after Hangfire 1.5.  Server identifiers are now generated using GUIDs, so all the instance names are unique. https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/running-multiple-server-instances.html

Answer (score 1):

According to current version of [Hangfire ASP.NET Core Applications](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html)
the call to `app.UseHangfireServer()` inside `public void Configure()` is not neccessary (at least the documentation does not include it)

instead, in `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`
use

```
services.AddHangfire
services.AddHangfireServer
```

This should eliminate the second server instance

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate queue for each server. Please look this page: [Single Dashboard, Single Physical Server, Multiple Jobs](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/single-dashboard-single-physical-server-multiple-jobs-projects-codebases-advice-or-examples/3677/3)